# How to store program permanently in a FPGA?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, fpga, vlsi

I was working on a project using FPGA and Arduino, in which i have to show for how long my fpga device was OFF  if it was so. I am using BASYS3 FPGA board. Once i switch off my FPGA the program is getting erased.

Comment: BASYS3 board uses an Artix-7 FPGA which is SRAM based. It does not hold its configuration over a power cycle.

Comment: FPGA on BASYS by it's nature can't store any program, because does not have any non volatile memory. You have to store it in on board flash memory.

Comment: Use the right FPGA. There are Flash-based ones.

Answer (score 6):

BASYS3 has quad spi FLASH onboard, fpga can be configured using stream stored there.

Follow instructions here: https://reference.digilentinc.com/learn/programmable-logic/tutorials/basys-3-programming-guide/start